# Python: Initiate integer without specifying value

Tags: python

Not sure why I can't find something on this but here's my question:

How do I initiate an integer without giving it a value so I can use it to solve equations.

E.g., if I specified that I had some integer x then I could write something that allows me to solve functions with respect to x.

E.g., an output might be: 2x+5

EX:

```
# Eisenstein Prime?
# 1J is complex number i
def eisenstein(a,b):
    w = e**((2*math.pi*1J)/3)
    z=a+b*w
    a = a+b*(w**2)
    print("Eisenstein Integer as z:")
    print(z)
    print("Omega as w:")
    print(w)
```

This outputs:

```
Eisenstein Integer as z:
(-0.9999999999999987+5.196152422706632j)
Omega as w:
(-0.4999999999999998+0.8660254037844387j)
```

I'd like to have the variable similar to how j appears above.

Comment: Can you show some Python code demonstrating what you want to do? It's not clear from your question. Python won't solve equations for you.

Comment: it's not really something I've been able to code since I have no idea how to do it. E.g., if I wanted to study complex numbers I can specify but I'll show an example of what I'd like it to do. One sec.

Comment: If you want to solve equations symbolically look into [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that with plain ints. You'll need to install [a package for symbolic mathematics](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html).

`python -m pip install sympy`

Then to use it,

```
import sympy as sp

x = sp.var('x')
equation = 2*x + 5

print(sp.solve([equation], [x]))
```

Output:

```
{x: -5/2}
```

The solver takes lists because it can do systems of equations. You can also just

```
sp.solve(equation, x)
```

And get

```
[-5/2]
```

---

Another example.

```
import sympy as sp

x, y = sp.var('x y')
equation = 2*x + 5*y  # Equations made this way are implicitly "= 0".

print(sp.solveset(equation, y, sp.S.Complexes))
```

Solved for `y`, note the output is in terms of `x`:

```
{-2*x/5}
```